# AJAX PHP contact form not working as a new input seems not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contact-form, ajaxform

I am trying to add one more input (called servizio) in this contact form but on submit I get an error message in the console 'Uncaught ReferenceError: servzio is not defined' even if it is defined in both JS and PHP file.

Can you please recognise if I am doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for your help

File contact.js

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
     * Contact form ajax
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */

    $('#contact-form').find('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var submit          = $('#contact-form submit');
            var ajaxResponse    = $('#contact-response');

            var name            = $("input#cname").val();
            var email           = $("input#cemail").val();
            var servizio        = $("input#cservizio").val();
            var message         = $("textarea#cmessage").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    servzio: servzio,
                    message: message,
                },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(result) {
                    submit.empty();
                    submit.append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result.sendstatus == 1) {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                        $form.fadeOut(500);
                    } else {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

This is the File contact.php

```
<?php

// Mail settings
$to      = "emiliano@dsasa.agency";
$subject = "asdsa's";

// You can put here your email
$header = "From: emiliano@dsadsa.agency\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

if ( isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["servizio"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

    $content  = "Name: "     . $_POST["name"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Email: "    . $_POST["email"]   . "\r\n";
    $content .= "servizio: " . $_POST["servizio"]; . "\r\n"
    $content .= "Message: "  . "\r\n" . $_POST["message"];

    if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $header)) {

        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Thanks for contacting us.",
            "sendstatus" => 1
        );

        echo json_encode($result);

    } else {

        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Sorry, something is wrong.",
            "sendstatus" => 0
        );

        echo json_encode($result);

    }

}
```

?>

This is the html

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form" novalidate="">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="cname">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="cname" class="form-control" name="cname" placeholder="Name*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="cservizio">1 Servizio Video o 2 Servizio Foto</label>
        <input type="text" id="cservizio" name="cservizio" class="form-control" placeholder="Indica il numero corrispondente al servizio">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="cemail">Your Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="cemail" name="cemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your E-mail*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="cmessage" name="cmessage" rows="7" placeholder="Message*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message."></textarea>
        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-d">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>

<!-- Ajax response -->
<div id="contact-response" class="ajax-response font-alt"></div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `servzio: servzio,`

Comment: Woo thank you so much @SearchAndResQ I thought was something worst :)

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Thanks for your help Now there are no errors in the console but I am not getting back the ajax response. It just add the wait status... Any idea?

Comment: Removing the && isset($_POST["servizio"])   and   $content .= "servizio: " . $_POST["servizio"]; . "\r\n"  it works sending the html response back

Comment: Go to the network tab in the browser and click on the php page and see if there are any messages

Comment: There are no errors 'Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK' and I can see all the form Data parsed correctly but the tab Response comes with This request has no response data available

Comment: Don't just remove the lines with errors.Try and fix the errors. The `$content .= "servizio: " . $_POST["servizio"]; . "\r\n"` has an error because the semicolon is misplaced.